# validating input text field (max and min) based on checkbox condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

What I am trying to do is to apply some validation on an input text field based on a checkbox and whether it is checked or not.

Case 1: when check box is selected, user can only enter numbers from 0 to 100 (decimal included. So 34.35 is allowed)

Case 2: Normal numeric validation

However the behavior of my code in Case 1 is it only allow user to enter 1 nu,beric digit between 1 to 9.

Here is my code.

HTML markup

```
elements.stakeInput = $('<input placeholder="0.00" type="text" style="float:right" />');
elements.promoMoneyCheckbox = $('<input type="checkbox" />');
```

JS

```
elements.promoMoneyCheckbox.click(function() {
        SingleDiv.prototype.validatePromoInputField(self);
    });

validatePromoInputField : function(singleDiv) {

        var self = this,
            elements = singleDiv.getElements(),
            promoMoneyCheckbox = elements.promoMoneyCheckbox;

        if (promoMoneyCheckbox.is(':checked')) {

            elements.stakeInput.attr("placeholder", "10.00");
            elements.stakeInput.keypress(function(event) {
                var num = parseInt(self.value, 10),
                    min = 0,
                    max = 100;

                if (isNaN(num)) {
                    this.value = "";
                    return;
                }

                this.value = Math.max(num, min);
                this.value = Math.min(num, max);
            })
        }
        else {
            elements.stakeInput.attr("placeholder", "00.00");
            validateInputs(event, 'decimal')
        }

    }

function validateInputs(event, typeOfInput) {

    event = event || window.event;
    if (event.ctrlKey || event.altKey || event.metaKey) return;

    var regex;
    switch (typeOfInput) {
        case 'decimal':
            regex = /^[.0-9]$/;
            break;
        case 'minAndMax':
            regex = // May be I could add a regex over here instead of the validating in validatePromoInputField fucntion
            break;
        default:
            regex = /^.$/;
            break;
    }

    var char = getKeypressChar(event);
    if (char == null || regex.test(char)) return;

    event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : (event.returnValue = false);

}
```

Is there any simple way to achieve this?

I am not looking for HTML5 validation i.e (input type="number" min and max value).

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery `.change()` event to detect changes of the input and `parseInt` to verify the input.

```
$("#in").change(function(e) {
    var val = parseInt($(this).val());
    if (!isNaN(val)) {
        if (val >= 0 && val < 100) {
            $("#out").html("good!");
            return;
        }
    }
    $("#out").html("bad!");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VxM4h/1/

Remember that client side changes can be altered. Make sure to verify your input on the server side as well.

Comment: How would I make sure that the user would not able to input any number in the text field if it is lets say ...10

Comment: Just add another conditional check to the second if clause: `if ((val >=0 && val < 100) && val != 10)`. Also `parseInt` automatically strips letters and smymbols from the input, e.g. "Asdf1" becomes "1"

Comment: I just realized i didn't check my comment properly. In your exmaple user is allowed to enter any numeric number including alphabets. What I need is to restrict the user to enter only NUMBERS which are greater than 10. Or else user should not be allowed to type anything else in the input field.